# Slow Query Execution in Export Site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, export

I have a site that contains several lists with look up columns also.

One of the lists contains > 800000 items in it.

and when I try to Export the Site, Site gets locked and Export gets hung.

After investigation a lot in ULS Logs found the following error.

This error comes only in this site other sites are migrated successfully.

I have a doubt that does sharepoint list support these much of data in list or not?

Please suggest.

---

> Slow Query Duration: 3757045.85485027
>
> 09/30/2013 05:50:05.52     PowerShell.exe (0x1DA8)
>   0x538C    SharePoint Foundation             Database
>   fa44    High        Slow Query StackTrace-Managed:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OnPostExecuteCommand(SqlCommand
>   command, SqlQueryData monitoringData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListItemObjectHelper.GetNextBatch()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ObjectHelper.RetrieveDataFromDatabase(ExportObject
>   exportObject)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ListItemObjectHelper.RetrieveData(ExportObject
>   exportObject)     at Microsoft...
>   a61d5192-de8c-4f3d-8b9b-06778051877e 09/30/2013 05:50:05.52*
>   PowerShell.exe (0x1DA8)                     0x538C    SharePoint
>   Foundation             Database                          fa44    High 
>   ....SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.GetObjectData(ExportObject
>   exportObject)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.ExportObjectManager.MoveNext()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.SerializeObjects()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExport.Run()     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletExport.InternalProcessRecord()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdlet.ProcessRecord()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoExecute()     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.PipelineNode.Execute(Array input, Pipe
>   outputPipe, ArrayList&...    a61d5192-de8c-4f3d-8b9b-06778051877e
>   09/30/2013 05:50:05.52*    PowerShell.exe (0x1DA8)
>   0x538C    SharePoint Foundation             Database
>   fa44    High        ... resultList, ExecutionContext context)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.ExecuteStatement(ParseTreeNode
>   statement, Array input, Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList,
>   ExecutionContext context)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.StatementListNode.Execute(Array input,
>   Pipe outputPipe, ArrayList& resultList, ExecutionContext context)
>   at System.Management.Automation.ParseTreeNode.Execute(Array input,
>   Pipe outputPipe, ExecutionContext context)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.ScriptCommandProcessor.ExecuteWithCatch(ParseTreeNode
>   ptn, Array inputToProcess)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.ScriptCommandProcessor.RunClause(ParseTreeNode
>   clause, Object dollarUnderbar, Object inputToProcess)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoComplete()     at
>   ...    a61d5192-de8c-4f3d-8b9b-06778051877e 09/30/2013 05:50:05.52*
>   PowerShell.exe (0x1DA8)                     0x538C    SharePoint
>   Foundation             Database                          fa44    High 
>   ...System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object
>   input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)     at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeHelper()
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalPipeline.InvokeThreadProc()
>   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineThread.WorkerProc() 
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   a61d5192-de8c-4f3d-8b9b-06778051877e

Answer (score 0):

The limit for SharePoint list items in one list is 30 million. Can you export the data from the list itself?

I had a similar problem when I exported and reimported the site multiple times. After some time the whole process was painfully slow and we recreated the site from scratch.

Comment: "Can you export the data from the list itself?"
Not able to export the data...

Comment: Is there any option to check I have this site in production. so can not recreate it again...